# What is the best way to send android notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I am making an android app and I need to send notifications across devices. For example, A performs an action and B will be notified about the A's action.

I have also WebSocket with background services but the battery doesn't like..

What is the best practice to do this?
And whats about firebase?

Thank you

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far and indicate specifically where you're having an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to use Push Notification. Firebase provides an excellent support to implement Push Notification. Please refer this for more information:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/